# Node Express app.listen(PORT) giving Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND base

Tags: express, server, localhost

I am running a Express server built in Node, and looking to have it binded to my local host with app.listen, here is the command in my server.js file.

```
"use strict";

const app = require("./app");
const { PORT } = require("./config");
console.log(PORT)

app.listen(PORT, function(err){
  if (err) console.log("Error in server setup")
  //no error being outputted here.
  console.log("Server listening on Port", PORT);
})
```

The port which is required from config is conditionally set to 3001, and printed out in the callback of `app.listen`, which means no (err) is being caught.

Yet the error I receive in the terminal is as follows:

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND base
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:108:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'base'
}
```

As I understand we just need to pass a port number to `app.listen()` in order to bind it to the localhost, but this error I am unsure about it. Your help is most appreciated. I have seen some variations of this issue but none with Express servers, so hoping that you can help me.

Tried to search various solutions and adding in a host parameter to the app.listen()
Tried to change the port number, tried also to hardcode the number in rather than it being dynamically selected in the config.

```
 "use strict";

/** Express app for jobly. */
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const { NotFoundError } = require("./expressError");
const { authenticateJWT } = require("./middleware/auth");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const companiesRoutes = require("./routes/companies");
const usersRoutes = require("./routes/users");
const jobsRoutes = require("./routes/jobs");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use(authenticateJWT);

app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/companies", companiesRoutes);
app.use("/users", usersRoutes);
app.use("/jobs", jobsRoutes);


/** Handle 404 errors -- this matches everything */
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  return next(new NotFoundError());
});

/** Generic error handler; anything unhandled goes here. */
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test") console.error(err.stack);
const status = err.status || 500;
const message = err.message;

return res.status(status).json({
error: { message, status },
});
```

});

module.exports = app;

Comment: Node can't resolve the `hostname: 'base'` via DNS. In other words, Node can't get an ip address for whatever `base` is. Have you defined that somewhere or are you making a request to there?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say for sure without seeing the includes, but with a couple of small changes I was able to make it work.

I used dotenv and stuck the PORT in an environment variable. there is a file name .env, and in it is PORT=3000.

Hopefully this is helpful:

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT;
console.log(PORT)

const app = express();
app.set("port", PORT || 3000);

app.listen(PORT, function(err){
  if (err) console.log("Error in server setup")
  //no error being outputted here.
  console.log("Server listening on Port", PORT);
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it has allowed me to see that the error was something with the app which I was importing via require from app.js, I have updated my code to include the express app. From what rI can see everything is above board, but still I get the base error, exclusively to this particualr express app.